# enable fields on form when bindingnavigator add new is clicked

Tags: winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I am using a BindingNavigator in my C# Winforms application.

I want the fields in my form to be disabled if there are no records in the bindingSource.
To do this I have placed the fields on a panel and want to bind the panel's enabled property using something like

```
this.panel1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", this, "HasRecord", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

this.bindingSource1.AddingNew += this.BindingSourceListAddingNew<Person>;
```

inside the form load event.

I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the form and set up a HasRecord property which does get invoked when the add new button is clicked

However I cant seem to find a property that will return true when the Add Button is clicked.
Here are the methods inside the form.

My question is, how do I get the HasRecord property to work?
I could add a module wide boolean variable and set it inside the BindingSourceAddingNew  but that seems like a hack.

```
    public bool HasRecord { get
    {
         return this.bindingSource1.Count > 0;

    } }

      public override void BindingSourceListAddingNew<T>(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        base.BindingSourceListAddingNew<T>(sender, e);
        this.SendChange("HasRecord");
        Debug.Print( this.bindingSource1.SupportsChangeNotification.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem seems related to bindingSource1.Count not being updated until *after* the AddingNew method is invoked. i.e. the first record you add still causes HasRecord to return a count of 0, hence the panel does not become enabled until the second record is added. Using the ListChanged event on the binding source instead seems to rectify this.

Using the following code causes the panel to be disabled on load and then enabled as soon as a record is added to bindingSource1 through button1_Click. You still have to raise the PropertyChanged manually though, I'm not sure if you were trying to avoid that.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool HasRecord
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bindingSource1.Count > 0; 
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.AddNew();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", this, "HasRecord", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }

    private void bindingSource1_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify
        OnPropertyChanged("HasRecord");
    }

}
```